# Magento 2 translate custom options

Tags: magento2, localisation

I created for a few products some custom options. Is it possible to translate these labels of the custom options? I have a translation .csv file, but adding it there didn't seem to work.

Comment: I have same problem (Magento 2.1.5), the process listed by Fabian Schmengler seems right, but in reality this is an existing issue reported from July 2016 : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5885

Answer (score 1):

Product data is not translated with CSV files **per language**, but stored **per store view**. Each store view has one language, so you should use the store specific values for translation.

Now this not only applies to product attributes but also to labels of custom options.

> 3. In the upper-left corner set **Store View** to the view for the translation. When prompted to confirm, tap <kbd>OK</kbd>.
> 4. For each field to be edited, do the following:
>
>    a.  Clear the **Use Default Value** checkbox to the right of the
>      field.
>
>    b.  Either paste or type the translated text into the field.
>
>    Make sure to translate all text fields, including image labels and Alt text, Search Engine Optimization fields and any **Custom Options**
>      information.
> 5. When complete, tap <kbd>Save</kbd>.

<sup>**Source:** [Magento 2.0 User Guide](http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-translate.html)</sup>

Comment: The problem with custom options is that it doesn't have a 'Use Default value' button. The values are also greyed out and not accessible. I'm in products->catalog->{{just a random item}}->custom options